# write data to csv file only separating fields with comma using c# string builder

Tags: c#, export-to-csv, stringbuilder

I need to write my data to csv file for below format.
"field1orow1","field2ofrow2","field3ofrow""field1ofrow2","field2ofrow2","field3ofrow2"
above format, after each row, the comma should not apply.and also line break should not.
here is my code

```
 var csvDataList = oCVFileDTO.Select(y => new { y.BatchNo, y.ItemName, y.Empno, y.GlCode, y.CostCenter, 
 y.TotalAmount, y.FinanceApprovedDate, y.ReferenceNo }).ToList();
                    DataTable dt = converter.ToDataTable(csvDataList);

                    string FileCSV = FilePath + FileName;
                    IEnumerable<string> columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                    Select(column => column.ColumnName);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("\"");
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        string[] fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).ToArray();
                        sb.Append(string.Join("\",\"", fields));
                        sb.Append("\"");
                        sb.Append(",");
                    }

                    File.WriteAllText(FileCSV, sb.ToString());
                    txtfilename.Text = string.Empty;
                    ShowMessage("CSV Export Successfully !");
```

but this won't output the format what i need. output of this is like this

> "field1ofrow1","field2ofrow1","field3ofrow1","field3ofrow1 "here it
>   applies a line break"  ","field1ofrow2","field2ofrow2","field3ofrow2"

Comment: Have you tried AppendJoin() method???

Comment: no. can you explain how to do that using it?

Comment: Can you show me what output you are expecting?